# JQuery find first child gives wrong result

Tags: jquery

```
<dl>
    <dt>title</dt>
    <dd>first
    </dd>
    <dd>second
    </dd>
    <dd> third
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Only the last try give me the correct result, is this a bug or anything wrong in my code? I use jquery 1.10.1. http://jsfiddle.net/RYJ9z/

```
var h=$("dl").find("dd:first-child").html();
alert(h);
var h2=$("dl").find("dd:nth-child(1)").html();
alert(h2);
var h3=$("dl").find("dd").first().html();
alert(h3);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("dl").find("dd:first-child")`: looks for an `dd` element which is the first child of its parent but `dt` element is the first child not `dd`

Try [:first-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-of-type)

`$("dl").find("dd:nth-child(1)")`: nth-child uses 1 based index so first child of the parent element is an `dt` element not `dd` so this also fails

Try [:nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-of-type)

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LMF7A/)